# Loading images on google map using AGM

Tags: angular, agm

I have one requirement to show/hide images on google map using agm something as shown below. I think there is some utility is available with AGM, however i am not aware of it.Below is my code to load map and on handleOnTilesLoaded() method I would like to add some code to load images

[image]

```
<agm-map [zoom]="5" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
    (mapClick)="mapClick($event)" (mapReady)="mapReady($event)"(tilesLoaded)="handleOnTilesLoaded()">  
 </agm-map>
```

Comment: I am also looking for similar kind of solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<agm-map [disableDefaultUI]="true" [zoomControl]="true" [zoom]=3 [usePanning]="true">
      <agm-overlay>
        <img src="../../assets/images/marker.png" >
      </agm-overlay>
      
    </agm-map>
```

Comment: This code sample worked for me perfectly.. Hope it will help you... cheers

Comment: Working.. Thanks